# OnResize Event for all browsers?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there was to fire an event upon the resizing of the window that would work for all browsers. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery, as usual, has a [cross-browser resize event](http://api.jquery.com/resize/).

Answer (score 0):

This should answer your question:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onresize = function () {
       <!-- YOUR CODE WILL GO HEAR -->
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Wrong answer, it is not supported in Chrome & Opera.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `document.body.onresize=function(){//your code}`.

I don't have opera. I have tested this on IE 9 and chrome.